# reverse linked list between given nodes in doubly linked list - algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am writing code for reversing doubly linked list between given nodes.

given this linked list `1->2->3->4->5`,

the function reverse(2,4) should result in
`1->4->3->2->5`.

the function takes two nodes, but not indices.

Here is what I have. I tried the Eclipse debugger to figure out why this runs indefinitely. for some reasons, I see the nodes being corrupted (Eclipse shows no data when I step through the line marked below)

```
public static void reverse(Node head, Node tail){
        Node prev=head.prev;
        Node current=head,next;
        while(current!=tail.next){
            next = current.next;
            current.next=prev;
            current.prev=next; //No data stepping after this point
            prev=current;
            current=next;
        }
    }

public static void main(String... args){
        Node one = new Node(1);
        Node two = new Node(2);
        Node three = new Node(3);
        Node four = new Node(4);
        Node five = new Node(5);

        five.setNodes(four, null);
        four.setNodes(three, five);
        three.setNodes(two,four);
        two.setNodes(one,three);
        one.setNodes(null, two);

        System.out.println("before reversing...");
        System.out.println(one);

        System.out.println("After reversing...");
        reverse(two,four);
        System.out.println(one);

}
```

Here is my node class

```
class Node {
     Node prev;
     Node next;
     int data;

     public Node(Node prev, Node next, int val){
         this.prev=prev;
         this.next=next;
         this.data=val;
     }

     public Node(int val){
         this(null,null,val);
     }

     public void setNodes(Node prev, Node next){
         this.next=next;
         this.prev=prev;
         }

     public String toString(){
         String toReturn = "[ " + this.data;

         Node current=this.next;
         while (current!=null){
             toReturn+=" -> " + current.data;
             current=current.next;
         }
         toReturn+=" ]";
         return toReturn;
     }

}
```

Comment: Is `Node current=head,next;` a typo (comma) ? It should have been `Node current=head.next;`

Comment: @brainstorm  take care with toString method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
public static void reverse(Node head, Node tail) {
    Node first = head;
    Node last = tail;
    while (first != last && first.prev != last) {
        Node preFirst = first.prev;
        Node postFirst = first.next;
        Node preLast = last.prev;
        Node postLast = last.next;
        if (preFirst != null) {
            preFirst.next = last;
        }
        if (postLast != null) {
            postLast.prev = first;
        }
        last.prev = preFirst;
        first.next = postLast;
        if (last != postFirst){
            last.next = postFirst;
            postFirst.prev = last;
            first.prev = preLast;
            preLast.next = first;
            first = postFirst;
            last = preLast;
        } else {
            last.next = first;
            first.prev = last;
        }
    }
}
```

Be carefuly with toString method, It's  very important, even for debugging!

```
public String toString(){
     String toReturn = "[ " + this.data;

     Node current=this.next;
     while (current!=null && current != this){ // <- cycle protection
         toReturn+=" -> " + current.data;
         current=current.next;
     }
     toReturn+=" ]";
     return toReturn;
 }
```

**EDIT**

It always returns the head node:

```
public static Node reverse(Node head, Node tail) {
    Node first = head;
    Node last = tail;
    while (first != last && first.prev != last) {
        Node preFirst = first.prev;
        Node postFirst = first.next;
        Node preLast = last.prev;
        Node postLast = last.next;
        if (preFirst != null) {
            preFirst.next = last;
        }
        if (postLast != null) {
            postLast.prev = first;
        }
        last.prev = preFirst;
        first.next = postLast;
        if (last != postFirst){
            last.next = postFirst;
            postFirst.prev = last;
            first.prev = preLast;
            preLast.next = first;
            first = postFirst;
            last = preLast;
        } else {
            last.next = first;
            first.prev = last;
        }
    }
    Node result = tail;
    while (result.prev != null){
        result = result.prev;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Node one = new Node(1);
    Node two = new Node(2);
    Node three = new Node(3);
    Node four = new Node(4);
    Node five = new Node(5);

    five.setNodes(four, null);
    four.setNodes(three, five);
    three.setNodes(two, four);
    two.setNodes(one, three);
    one.setNodes(null, two);

    System.out.println("before reversing...");
    System.out.println(one);

    System.out.println("After reversing...");
    one = reverse(one, three);
    System.out.println(one);
}
```

prints:

```
before reversing...
[ 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 ]
After reversing...
[ 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 5 ]
```

Comment: as I walk through my code above in paper, I see it should work. but it does not!. thanks for pointing bug in toString method

Comment: @brainstorm You must to swap the pair of nodes!Think in pre-head and post-tail must be correct linked, you should be able to reverse an odd/pair number of nodes  (2,4) and (3,4)

Comment: why you do swap? you have to reverse between given nodes.

Comment: btw, did you try reverse(two,five) with your code? it does not work

Comment: because it's a double linked list, you need to preserve previous and next references.  If you reverse this list `1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8` between 2 and 7,  a first step can be to swap (2,7) `1->7->3->4->5->6->2->8` and repeat with (3,6),  (4,5).

Comment: I get your point. but your code did not work with reverse(two,five). I guess it is because of swap thinking

Comment: @brainstorm sorry, edited! the null protection was overreached!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101439/discussion-between-brain-storm-and-david-perez-cabrera).

Comment: did you try reverse(one,three)?

Comment: @brainstorm yes, and it works! try to System.out.println(three); after reverse (one, three)

Comment: Try System.out.println(one); basically reversing the first three nodes of the five nodes

Comment: @brainstorm after reversing, one is not the head! three is head!

Comment: yes, I realized that. so the method should return head ?

Comment: @brainstorm I've tried to preserve the original interface, but here I edited for your suggestion

Comment: why do you have this check in while loop? `first.prev != last`?

Comment: @brainstorm for reversing a pair number of nodes. Example: `1->2->3->4->5->6` `reverse(2,5)` -> (1st) `1-5-3-4-2-6` (2nd) -> `1-5-4-3-2-6` and now first:3, last:4 and the reverse is done.